# PHP: Remove third item in 4 items comma list "1,2,3,4"

Tags: php, slice

How can I delete the 3 in "1,2,3,4"?

Dirty hack: Slice the sliced arrays and join them again.

```
$s = "1,2,3,4";

$array = explode(',', $s);
$a = array_splice($array, 0, -2);
$b = array_splice($array, 1, 1);
$s = implode(',', $a).','.implode($b);

echo $s; // 1,2,4
```

Test: http://codepad.org/WeDLKvEE

Comment: try unset($array[2]);

Comment: unset() yay! http://codepad.org/C85nOhdk Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK.  How about using strpos and instr?  Find the second comma and the third one.

Comment: Sorry, no. I dunno the values. People use dummy strings ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = "1,2,3,4";
$array = explode(',', $s); 
unset($array[2]);
$Arr = array_values($array); 
print_r($Arr);
```

demo : https://eval.in/85585

Comment: @Martin: did you want it?

Answer (score 0):

How about this, by this you do not depend on the position of the string rather can wipe out by value.

```
$s = "1,2,3,4";
$array = explode(",",$s);
$val = 3 ;
$key = array_search($val,$array);
if($key!==false){
    unset($array[$key]);
}

echo implode(",",$array); // 1,2,4
```